# Proof that $x^3+y^4=z^{31}$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question from RMO 2015.

Show that there are infinitely many triples (x,y,z) of integers such that $x^3+y^4=z^{31}.$

This is how I did my proof:
Suppose $z=0,$ which is possible because $0$ is an integer. Then $x^3+y^4=0 \Rightarrow y^4=-x^3.$ Now, suppose $y$ is a perfect cube such that it is of the form $a^3$ where $a$ is any integer. Then $(a^3)^4=-x^3 \Rightarrow a^{12}=-x^3,$ whereby $x=-(-a)^4.$ Hence there exists infinitely many triples {x,y,z}={$-(-a)^4, a^3, 0$}, which satisfy $x^3+y^4=z^{31}$ for every integer $a$.

However the solution that they have given is quite different from mine. What I want to know is that, is my solution valid, and is this a convincing method to do proofs of such kind?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your solution is valid! Their solution cannot be very different! Can you show us the solution?

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure whether this was a proper proof..

Comment: Yeah, i'll do that

Comment: Nothing wrong with your method.  Perhaps the question was intended to exclude $0$ from the triple.

Comment: @lulu According to the official source [http://www.isical.ac.in/~rmo/papers/rmo/rmo-2015-3.pdf](http://www.isical.ac.in/~rmo/papers/rmo/rmo-2015-3.pdf) it wasn't (although the solution looks like it was, so who knows...)

Comment: Yeah, the question never mentions positive integers. Thanks guys!

Comment: By looking at your solution below, it was probably a mistake that the question missed the word "positive". It will be a litter harder to find positive solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to obtain **positive** integer solutions.

Let $n$ be any positive integer such that
$$3\mid n \quad \quad 4\mid n \quad \quad 31 \mid (n+1)$$
There are infinitely many such $n$ by Chinese Reminader Theorem,
then $x^3 = 2^n$, $y^4 = 2^n$, $z^{31} = 2^{n+1}$ satisfies $x^3+y^4=z^{31}$.

Comment: I don't know the Chinese Remainder Theorem yet....But your solution looks quite elegant!

Comment: This solution is actually the same to the one you posted, except mine avoids some calculations on finding $n$.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation on the 'official' solution: instead of proving that the equation $12r+1=31k$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions we find a particular one, let's say $k=7,r=18$; it follows that $x=2^{4\cdot 18},y=2^{3\cdot 18},z=2^7$ is a particular solution for our equation and from here it is easy to notice that 
$$x=2^{4\cdot 18}\cdot k^{4\cdot 31},y=2^{3\cdot 18}\cdot k^{3\cdot 31},z=2^{7}\cdot k^{3\cdot 4}$$
is also a solution for the given equation, for any positive integer $k$.

Comment: Nice manipulation!

Answer (score 0):

Small changes to a problem can change the solution. The problem was to show that there are infinitely many positive integer solutions.

See [here](http://www.cheenta.com/2015/12/06/regional-math-olympiad-rmo-2015-west-bengal/).

Comment: But it doesn't mention about positive integers, it only says "triples in integers that satisfy..."

Comment: @WTS Maybe the source from where you got the statement didn't have the word positive. In the link I posted it does have it. For positive solutions the problem is a little more interesting and justifies the extra trouble that you didn't have to take solving your version of the problem.

Comment: Then it must be a printing mistake.... so my solution is not valid.

Comment: @WTS Well, it just depends on what statement is being proven. Yours is valid for your statement. It is not enough for the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution they gave...

Choose $x = 2^{4r}$ and $y = 2^{3r}$. Then the left side is $2^{12r+1}$. If we take$ z = 2^k$,
then we get$ 2^{12r+1} = 2^{31k}$. Thus it is sufficient to prove that the equation 12r + 1 = 31k
has infinitely many solutions in integers. Observe that$ (12.18) + 1 = 31.7$. If we choose
$r = 31l + 18$ and $k = 12l + 7$, we get
$12(31l + 18) + 1 = 31(12l + 7)$;
for all$ l$. Choosing $l\in N$, we get infinitely many$ r = 31l + 18$ and$ k = 12l + 7$ such that
$12r + 1 = 31k$. Going back we have infinitely many (x; y; z) of integers satisfying the given
equation.

Comment: So they want positive integer solutions! Then your solution is not valid!

Comment: @Ghartal This just means they focused on positive integers in solution, but problem statement does not say anything about positive... But it could be a mistake.