# Show that there are infinitely many prime triples $(x,y,z) $ of integers such that $x^3 + y^4 = z^{31}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Show that there are infinitely many prime triples $(x,y,z) $ of integers such that $x^3 + y^4 = z^{31}$.

This question would have been relatively much easier and I would have been able to do it if they had not asked for prime triples. But I have no idea how to solve this question for prime triples.

If we just assume $x=-t^{4}, y=t^{3}$ and $z=0$, we can show that there are infinitely many composite solutions. No idea for how to do it for prime numbers.

EDIT- This question was asked in RMO 2015[Not Romania]. I got this question from aops which gave me the wrong question. Read the comments written by lulu to know what was wrong. Still, it would be great if someone can solve it for prime numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you want prime solutions?  Meaning, I guess, that all three must be prime?  That seems difficult.  The [original RMO problem](https://www.isical.ac.in/~rmo/papers/rmo/rmo-2015-3.pdf) from which this was taken does not require primes.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326050/proof-that-x3y4-z31-has-infinitely-many-solutions)

Comment: Side note:   despite the phrasing of the RMO problem, I expect that the question was intended to search for $\textit {positive}$ solutions, just to avoid the $z=0$ case you cite (and similar cases when $x$ or $y$ are $0$).

Comment: Wow, thanks $@lulu$. I was solving this question on <https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c854399_2015_india_regional_mathematicai_olympiad>. and they gave me the wrong question. :-(

Comment: Yeah, I expect they just had that wrong.  If there's any way to get solutions in primes, I'd love to see it.

Comment: So, I think I will just edit the question.

Comment: If there are any solutions in the primes, since at least one of the terms must be even, one of the primes  would have to be $2$.

Comment: I made earlier comments ( self deleted) about how mod 4, and mod 6, and other's with totient 2 force both 2, and 3 involved. Because, $x+1\equiv z$ is the reduced for in these cases.

Comment: FWIW, $z=2$ provides no solutions. $2^{31}=2147483648$. Hence $y\le \sqrt[4] 2147483648 =215.27$ Decrementing $2147483648$ by the fourth power of every prime $<215$ yield no perfect cubes. Hence $x$ or $y$ must be $2$.

Comment: Knowing that $x$ or $y$ must be $2$, it is easy to show that neither of the other two can be $3$. Hence, if they exist, they would have to be odd primes of the form $6m\pm 1$.

Comment: Following up on the previous comments by Keith, $x$ cannot be equal to $2$, as otherwise the left-hand side is congruent to $0 \pmod{3}$. So $y$ must be equal to $2$. Then looking at the equation modulo $3$, modulo $7$ and modulo $16$ we get $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, $z \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, $z \equiv 1,3 \pmod{7}$ and $x \equiv z \pmod{16}$.